# how can I create a bitmaped data in c?

Tags: c++, c, bitmap, embedded

I am trying to create a bitmaped data in , here is the code I used but I am not able to figure the right logic. Here's my code

```
bool a=1;
bool b=0;
bool c=1;
bool d=0;

uint8_t output = a|b|c|d;

printf("outupt = %X", output);
```

I want my output to be "1010" which is equivalent to hex "0x0A". How do I do it ??

Comment: output should be 1. I mean you have 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 which is 1.

Comment: Do you know about the bitwise *shift* opreators `<<` and `>>`? Perhaps you should consider a [decent book or two](https://stackoverflow.com/a/388282/440558)?

Comment: @Scheff While that is true, we do not remove the C++ tag when there are C++ answers present, because that might render those answers bad and off-topic. Please see the tag usage guidlines in C and C++ tag wikis. I did a rollback.

Comment: @Scheff People who write answers don't always check the question carefully - they might follow either only the C or only the C++ tag and then assume the question is in that language. So they write an answer in good faith. If we remove the C++ tag, then those answers come across as off-topic and may attract down votes for that reason alone.

Comment: @Scheff You have to click on the "learn more" option in top of those links. (Thanks to recent UI changes, it is now even harder to find than before...) Here is the [C tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c/info) and [C++ tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/info).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The bitwise or operator *or*s the bits in each position. The result of `a|b|c|d` will be `1` because you're bitwise *or*ing 0 and 1 in the *least* significant position.

You can shift (`<<`) the bits to the correct positions like this:

```
uint8_t output = a << 3 | b << 2 | c << 1 | d;
```

This will result in

```
    00001000 (a << 3)
    00000000 (b << 2)
    00000010 (c << 1)
  | 00000000 (d; d << 0)
    --------
    00001010 (output)
```

Strictly speaking, the calculation happens with `int`s and the intermediate results have more leading zeroes, but in this case we do not need to care about that.

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in setting/clearing/accessing very simply specific bits, you could consider **[`std::bitset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset)**:

```
bitset<8> s;   // bit set of 8 bits

s[3]=a;        // access individual bits, as if it was an array
s[2]=b;
s[1]=c; 
s[0]=d;        // the first bit is the least significant bit

cout << s <<endl;       // streams the bitset as a string of '0' and '1' 
cout << "0x"<< hex << s.to_ulong()<<endl;    // convert the bitset to unsigned long
cout << s[3] <<endl;     // access a specific bit
cout << "Number of bits set: " << s.count()<<endl;
```

[Online demo](https://ideone.com/zo14wX)

The advantage is that the code is easier to read and maintain, especially if you're modifying bitmapped data. Because setting specific bits using binary arithmetics with a combination of `<<` and `|` operators as explained by [Anttii](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63875664/3723423) is a vorkable solution.  But clearing specific bits in an existing bitmap, by combining the use of `<<` and `~` (to create a bit mask) with `&` is a little more tricky.

Another advantage is that you can easily manage large bitsets of hundreds of bits, much larger than the largest built-in type `unsigned long long`  (although doing so will not allow you to convert as easily to an unsigned long or an unsigned long long:  you'll have to go via a string).

Answer (score -1):

## C only

I would use bitfields. I know that they are not portable, but for the particular embedded hardware (especially uCs) it is well defined.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>


typedef union 
{
    struct 
    {
        bool a:1;
        bool b:1;
        bool c:1;
        bool d:1;
        bool e:1;
        bool f:1;
    };
    unsigned char byte;
}mydata;


int main(void)
{
    mydata d;

    d.a=1;
    d.b=0;
    d.c=1;
    d.d=0;

printf("outupt = %hhX", d.byte);
}
```

Comment: No they are well-defined per _specific compiler_ for the specific hardware. If you are to change compiler at any point in the product's life time, it may not behave identically. Particularly when it comes to padding bits & bytes and supported types.

Comment: Also, this code gives 0101, not 1010, assuming the compiler placed `a` at LSB, so it gives the wrong output on most compilers (but not guaranteed).

Comment: @Lundin uC programming is very specific and people very rarely change the compiler, and most of the compilers for particular platform (for example Cortex M) follow the same path. Portability with AS-400 is not the issue which bothers uC developers.

Comment: I pretty much exclusively program microcontrollers and I quite often change compiler. This happens when the original programmer picked some freeware toolchain they found in a packet of corn flakes provided by the silicon vendor. Then eventually the team decides that they can't spend weeks of their time chasing IDE bugs (Eclipse, anyone?) or chase down non-existent tool support, then switch to a better toolchain. Also, most professional microcontroller systems implement MISRA-C and doing that will be a nightmare if you allow bit-fields.

Comment: @P__J__: Maybe our embedded processors or SoCs are not that small, but it is still very deeply embedded. And we have here multiple core architectures on processor like a DSP + Cortex-M4 + Cortex-R5F. And since our ECUs are ASIL-B (and soon maybe higher), we need qualified compilers, which the gcc and clang are not. Not to mention, that the DSP compiler is a completely different compiler than the ARM core compilers. But the cores might share the same data between them. So, your answer is very biased.